# How to return a promise that waits for isLoaded to be true

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a property isLoaded on the object document. document stores information about a specific project. When I open a project, the code loads the document and sets isLoaded to true.

How can I return a promise that waits for isLoaded to be true? I want to do X (trigger some other code) when isLoaded is true. How can I do this using javascript?

Comment: I suppose you could wrap a `setInterval` operation in a `Promise`, in which it periodically checks the value and resolves when the value is `true`.  Though what would ever cause the `Promise` to reject?  This sounds like it may be an XY Problem.  Can you elaborate on the underlying problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: It would be useful if you can provide some code to show the problem you are solving.

Comment: how is `isLoaded` "triggered" (other than by reading almost any post on facebook)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by using a JavaScript Promise along with a setTimeout or an event-based approach.

Example:-

```
  function waitForLoaded(documentStore) {
return new Promise((resolve) => {
  const checkIsLoaded = () => {
    if (documentStore.isLoaded === true) {
      resolve(); 
    } else {
      setTimeout(checkIsLoaded, 100); 
    }
  };

  checkIsLoaded(); 
});
}


waitForLoaded(yourDocumentStoreObject)
.then(() => {
  console.log('isLoaded is now true. Executing X...');
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error waiting for isLoaded:', error);
});
```

Comment: I like this answer, given the absolute lack of any real information in the question

Comment: maybe reject the promise after a longer timeout as well, so it doesn't remain pending forever if the store is never loaded for some reason.

Comment: @DustInComp - nah, let the OP suffer :p